# PHP generate json - list of categories

Tags: php, json

Hi I need to generate json code with php like this http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

Comment: Ok.. get started with: http://us2.php.net/json

Comment: No one is stopping you. Get cracking!

Comment: use php fuction json_encode($array)

Comment: I do not know to write array so that it looked like this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an multi-dimensional array with the json_encode function to achieve this structure.

$var = array(
    "contacts" => array (
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "foo"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "bar"
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($var);

Comment: Do you have any idea how to add to while?

Comment: What does add to while mean?

Comment: I need adding contacts from db (while)

Comment: I dont have any idea about while. You could achieve this structure if you know how arrays work in php.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for json_encode(). Passing an associative array to it will return a JSON representation.

https://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: I do not know to write array so that it looked like this